# What does it mean if there's no peaks on raman spectrum?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, spectroscopy, data-analysis, raman-spectroscopy

I carried out Raman measurements of a doped semiconductor. I know what are the peaks of undoped one. I also know, that usually doped semiconductor has at least few peaks in similar positions to the undoped version.

However, today one of the samples gave signal that looks like this:
[image]

When I zoom it a lot, I can find no reasonable peak.
To sum up:

- What does this shape of spectrum mean, and why?
- What are the causes for lack of peaks?

Comment: If in the unfolded case you would see peaks, then likely this is experimental error.

Comment: @JonCuster Can you tell me please what is "unfolded case"?

Comment: Hmmmm.... Looks like auto-correct went wild. 'Undoped' must not be in the dictionary on my phone. Sigh.